# jshell use external dependency from Maven repository

Tags: java, jshell

I'd like to use JShell to launch a Class which is contained in a Maven repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
    <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Looking at the docs, I can see you can specify the classpath using the following option:

```
jshell --class-path=
```

That however implies that you have the library locally. I wonder if it's possible to just specify the Maven GAV or an HTTP URL to pick up the Class from that dependency. Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a `pom.xml` with all your dependencies listed, a simple solution is to symlink or copy the jars you need to a single directory, say `$HOME/.java/lib` and launch jshell like this:

```
CLASSPATH=$HOME/.java/lib/*:. jshell
```

If you do have a `pom.xml` in the current directory, you can do this:

```
CLASSPATH=`mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeTypes=jar -Dmdep.outputFile=/dev/stderr 2>&1 >/dev/null`:target/classes jshell
```

Note, because of [JDK bug 8177650](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177650), you probably don't want to use the --class-path option.